# Get-PnPSiteTemplate to get out the xml for Files

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, provisioning, pnp-provisioning

There are files stored in my sites which I would like to take xml out of so when I run invoke it will upload those files to another site. But I can only get files sometimes when I use  `Get-PnPSiteTemplate -Out c:\temp.xml -PersistBrandingFiles` . Is there a specific way I can get the xml of the files out. The sort of sample I am looking for is as following:

```
<pnp:Files>
        <pnp:File Src="SiteAssets/SitePages/TestSite/style.jpg" Folder="SiteAssets/SitePages/TestSite" Overwrite="true" Level="Published" />     
  
        <pnp:File Src="SiteAssets/SitePages/TestSite/41.jpg" Folder="SiteAssets/SitePages/TestSite" Overwrite="true" Level="Published" />
</pnp:Files>
```

`

Comment: Did you try below steps. Please mark as answer if satisfied

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps.

1. Get PnP Site Template including List and Branding.

> Get-PnPSiteTemplate -Out template.pnp -PersistBrandingFiles -Handlers
> Lists

2. Add File to PnP Site Template

> Add-PnPFileToSiteTemplate -Path template.pnp -SourceUrl
> "Shared%20Documents/ProjectStatus.docx"

Adds a file to a PnP Provisioning Template retrieved from the currently connected site. The url can be server relative or web relative. If specifying a server relative url has to start with the current site url.

Reference

[Add-PnPFileToSiteTemplate](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Add-PnPFileToSiteTemplate.html)